# "beforeinstallprompt" prompt() causes infinite useEffect loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, progressive-web-apps, gatsby

*e.prompt()* derived from `beforeinstallprompt` causes in infinite *useEffect* loop.

On `beforeinstallprompt`, *handle_storePrompt()* sets *showButton* to true (`<button />` "display:block"). OnClick, *handle_prompt()* sets *showButton* to false (`<button />` "display:none"). After *prompt()* is resolved, `beforeinstallprompt` is against fired causing *handle_storePrompt()* to run again.

**Component**

```
const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState(false)
const [prompt, setPrompt] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
    const handle_storePrompt = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log('Action Triggered')
        setPrompt(e)
        setShowButton(true)
    }

    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', e =>
        handle_storePrompt(e)
    )

    return _ => {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', e =>
            handle_storePrompt(e)
        )
    }
}, [])

const handle_prompt = _ => {
    setShowButton(false)
    prompt.prompt()
}

return (
    <button className={showButton ? Styles.show : ''} onClick={handle_prompt}>
        <small>Click to Install</small>
    </button>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by removing `setShowButton(true)` from *handle_storePrompt()* and initializing *showButton* state as true.

Moving forward, *showButton* can initialize with a local storage date variable to prevent `<button />` from displaying every visit/refresh.

```
const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState(true)
const [prompt, setPrompt] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
    const handle_storePrompt = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (showButton) setPrompt(e)
    }

    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', e =>
        handle_storePrompt(e)
    )

    return _ => {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', e =>
            handle_storePrompt(e)
        )
    }
}, [showButton])

const handle_prompt = _ => {
    setShowButton(false)
    prompt.prompt()
    setPrompt(null)
}

return (
    <button className={showButton ? Styles.show : ''} onClick={handle_prompt}>
        <small>Click to Install</small>
    </button>
)
```